# How to rewrite URL without refresh, like GitHub.com

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was browsing GitHub.com and I noticed when looking at the source for a repository, and you click on a file, the source code slides in and the URL changes, but it doesn't appear as if the page has refreshed. Does anyone know how this is done? I've seen this done with the # sign, especially when creating Flash sites, but I've never seen this done quite like the way GitHub is doing it, without the #.

Here's an example:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Click on one of the text files like .gitattributes then click on jQuery in the breadcrumb to see what I mean.

Comment: It navigates to a new page over here...

Comment: Doing a little more research it looks like this might be a webkit/Safari only feature.

Comment: On some browsers, the page repaint is a little less abrupt, so it looks smoother, but I think it is loading a new page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is used on the client-side in Chrome/Webkit browsers to fetch server-side resources without page refreshing, and content is dynamically loaded in, and animations can be hooked in during that content being appended.

I'm not sure exactly why only Chrome is targeted by the ajax, as usually the hash mark changes when ajax is applied in the same manner ( like twitter ).

<del>For the url changing dynamically, I believe all that's done is `location.href` is updated.</del> On second thought, it could be some new HTML5 feature that only chrome supports.

Comment: The AJAX part isn't really what I was interested in, I'm more interested in how the URL is changing without refreshing the page.

Comment: I think it might have to do with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: yep, it's `history.pushState`

Comment: Pretty cool, huh? It looks like it works on Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Sandro - Fx4? My 3.5 doesn't use `history.pushState`

Comment: My mistake, looks like it only works on Safari and Chrome for me.

Comment: @meder Fx4+ supports it too. Fx3.5 is too old and unsupported now.

Answer (score 13):

Github uses window.history.replaceState()

[Here](https://gist.github.com/730603) you can see how they do it

Comment: Awesome, this was only a dream of mine back when I first started trying to do this and found for security purposes you had to use the hash trick instead.

Answer (score 2):

I found this article which explains these HTML5 features - window.history.pushState(), window.history.replaceState() and the onpopstate() event: http://www.spoiledmilk.dk/blog/?p=1922

As the article mentions, Flickr is also using this technique in several places.

Comment: The link is dead. Can you find another, similar source, by any chance?