# Change url with javascript without page refresh

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rewrite URL without refresh, like GitHub.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371705/how-to-rewrite-url-without-refresh-like-github-com)

Hi all,

I have a list of href links (but1 - but4) that I can click. The data is preloaded and stored as JSON. When I click a link, I would like to change the URL, eg fakeURL.com -> fakeURL.com/but1

I know this can be done by using the window.location.hash function, but I'd prefer to modify the url directly.

An example of this is github (https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common) where if you click on a folder in a repository, the url changes and the folder is loaded (via AJAX, so slightly different, but if I understood their solution I can modify to my case)

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks,
djs22

EDIT: I'd prefer a solution more robust than html5 history.pushState .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371705/how-to-rewrite-url-without-refresh-like-github-com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to change the url. That would be a huge security flaw. I can't find any ajax at github, the page reloads, and a new url is displayed. The only part of the url that can be changed with javascript is the hash-part.

Comment: You sure? It looks like only the file structure is being reloaded? Is there any way to test this directly?

Comment: You can use firebug (addon for firefox) to view ajax-requests and their responses etc. It clearly shows that there are no ajax-requests when browsing folders at github.

Comment: @djs22: github uses `history.pushState` (in browsers that support it). If you don't want to use the hash, then **there is no other way**.

Comment: @TheQ: Are you using Firfox 3.6 by any chance? ;)

Comment: I sure am. Which i guess don't support history.pushState then :)

Comment: @TheQ: Yep ;) Firefox 4 does...

Comment: Chrome does this fine. FireFox 3.6 doesn't maybe that is the problem