# change url address using Javascript

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rewrite URL without refresh, like GitHub.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371705/how-to-rewrite-url-without-refresh-like-github-com)

let say I have variable in Javascript

```
var currentpage = 0;
```

my address page address  is **www.xyz.com/page/1**

when I click somewhere and js function trigger

```
currentpage = 1
//Here I want to change/rewrite www.xyz.com/page/2
//Without redirecting to this page
```

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to rewrite the URL displayed in the browser bar without actually changing the page that you're on?

Answer (score 5):

See [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method) (browser support currently limited).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You have to use the '#' or '#!' notation and pass the page number after it, then do trigger some js on load to figure out which page to display.