# How to let an <a> no-refresh and redirect a page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rewrite URL without refresh, like GitHub.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371705/how-to-rewrite-url-without-refresh-like-github-com)

For example,Google Plus's navbar done it:
If you click a navbar's button,you will see a div is updated,**and the URL is changed**.
Can't ajax?How to do it?
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

not ajax,it seems unlikely.
but you can imitate to update but url is not changed

```
<a href="###" onclick="update()"/>
```

the function update,you can send a request by ajax

Answer (score 0):

They do 3 things:

1. Load the data by using ajax
2. They change the url of the page (notice - the page is not loaded, just the querystring changes).
3. They push this url to the history of the browser.

all these are possible with the use of javascript.