# updating website url on click of anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I have a website that contains link to some other page. I have used ajax to dynamically send request to server. When I click on link it opens other page but url of page does not changes.
It remains same.
How to update the url, so that link opens in same page as well as url changes ?? and the last part I have link in Iframe so I want to update parent window url but it still should not refresh?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rewrite URL without refresh, like GitHub.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371705/how-to-rewrite-url-without-refresh-like-github-com)